# Hive Update 0.14 version is not working Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.“

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to update hive orc bucket table. but it throwing exception FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.“
I'm running in hive Command prompt.

STEP 1:

```
set hive.support.concurrency = true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
SET hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
SET hive.compactor.worker.threads = 1;
```

STEP  2:

create table test(id int ,name string ) clustered by (id) into 2 buckets stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');

STEP 3:
insert into table test values (1,'row1'),(2,'row2'),(3,'row3'); -- 3 rows inserted successfully
STEp 4 :

insert into table testTable values (1,'row1'),(2,'row2');

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.“

After this when I  open another hive prompt and run show tables, it remains in hang state no results are return. I restart hive services also but no use.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Hive [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML), Bucketing and Partitioning columns cannot be updated. Can you retry by using a column other than `id`?